# Truncate all numbers after decimal

Tags: python, decimal

How do you truncate all numbers after a decimal in Python 3?

For example truncate 3.444 to be just 3.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By converting it to an `int`:

```
>>> num = 3.444
>>> int(num)
3
```

Comment: A more comprehensive explanation would be appreciated I guess ;)

Comment: @cartman: Not sure; this is a site for programmers; can we request a modicum of CS knowledge here?

Comment: Why would it need to be more comprehensive? Integers can't have decimal places, period.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right but, I meant an explanation like 3.444 is a floating point number and you convert it to an integer etc.

Comment: What if the number is a large number?

Comment: @Jeff: what about it? Python integers support arbitrarily large numbers limited only by memory. It's the float precision you'd need to worry about; you cannot produce a large enough `float` value (outside of `float('inf')`) to ever dent your memory when converted to an integer.

Comment: I think I was under the impression that int only went up to a relatively small number. I was thinking I would have to round, then truncate after the decimal.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import math
>>> num = 3.4444
>>> math.trunc(num)
3
```

Comment: What is the different between "math.trunc" and "int" functions?